# Family Sharing "No purchases"

Tags: applications, family-sharing

I just set up family sharing. I'm the organizer and I enabled purchase and location sharing... I can see my sister's purchases but she can't see mine. Also she can see my location but no my purchases, why?

Comment: FS is very buggy

Comment: Now it works. Lately Apple software seems very buggy to me.

Comment: iOS 11 though...